# Web API 2: ApiController.User property not matching Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm porting an ASP.NET Web API application to the Web API 2 release candidate. This application uses a MessageHandler to authorise a user by parsing and decrypting an HTTP header. It then creates an appropriate ClaimsPrincipal and sets both `HttpContext.Current.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

In Web API 1.0, controllers could access the `ApiController.User` property and get the principal I set earlier in the message handler. In Web API 2.0 the User property contains an effectively blank `GenericPrincipal`, even though `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is correct.

Is this intentional? Is it a bug with web API 2 (very possible)? Perhaps I am not setting the principal correctly?

I've been using `ApiController.User` as it seemed 'more correct' than going straight to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, but that's always a possible solution to the issue.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I would suggest using the new HttpRequestContext.Principal as the place to store your Principal.

Comment: `ApiController.User` is just an alias for `RequestContext.Principal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while, but it turns out this was an issue in the RC which is fixed in the final release of Web API 2. Works fine now!